# Example of functor not full not faithfull

Tags: category-theory, functors

I am trying to find a functor that is not full nor faithful, if anyone can give me any suggestion, I appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Looking at two groups $G,G'$ as categories with one object, functors $G\to G'$ identify with group homomorphisms. Any non injective non surjective group homomorphism will do then.

Answer (score 2):

A constant functor (all objects map to the same object, all morphisms to the identity morphism) is usually neither full nor faithful.